# Fusion chart with Data grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, fusioncharts

I am using fusion chart in my dashboard.
When I click a bar, I want to see the details as a data grid in the bottom of the graph.
How can I achieve...? I am using asp.net.
Please get me a sample code or any reference link.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the following article from their official site. It shows on mouse hover you will get the bar details. You can download the project [here](http://www.fusioncharts.com/resources/dev-resources/javascript-charts-with-asp-dot-net/) and just change `onmouseover` to `onclick` event so details will be seen on mouse click.